# How I can apply this AJAX request without reloading the page to take effect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, ejs

This is a to-do app. Whenever I click on "Add" it needs to reload the page so that it takes effect and you can actually see the items.

I want to make the request AJAX where it doesn't need to refresh the page. How I can do that?

I use Express for servers, EJS for view engine.

This is Server stuff for the app:

```
let items = [];
module.exports = function(app, urlencoded) {
  app.get("/todo", function(req, res) {
    res.render("toDo", { data: items });
  });
  app.post("/todo", urlencoded, function(req, res) {
    items.push(req.body);
    console.log(req.body);
  });
  app.delete("/todo:item", function(req, res) {});
};
```

This is the script that I use it to send an AJAX request:

```
let btn = document.querySelector("button");
let itemValue = document.querySelector("input").value;
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "/todo", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  xhr.send(
    JSON.stringify({
      item: itemValue
    })
  );
});
```

And this is the HTML(EJS) file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>To-do Application</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../Public/Assets/Styles.css" />
  <script src="../Public/Scripts/Add.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="todo-table">
    <form onsubmit="return false;">
      <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Write an item here" required>
      <button id="Add">Add</button>
    </form>
    <ul>
      <% data.forEach(function(element){ %>
        <li> <%= element.item %> </li>
      <% }) %>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add `res.render("/todo");` at the end of the `add.post` function.

Comment: @Arihant It doesn't work. I will still need to refresh it.

Comment: @Arihant Also it's not "/todo" it's just "todo" because it's a file, not a path.

Comment: What is the html, js file names.. Is the `console.log`  inside `app.post` getting printed ?

Comment: Sorry it is `res.redirect("/todo");`

Comment: @Arihant Yeah, they get all printed.

Comment: Try adding `res.redirect("/todo");` at the end of the `add.post` function. Hope this works.

Comment: @Arihant I don't see how that's going to make it have an AJAX effect at all. It will just redirect it to that url which is going to refresh it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. I just made the `<li>` myself when the request successes then I loaded them when the page gets ready. I also removed the data thing for ejs as I found them the problem since they only render when the page gets refreshed/loaded, next time I will use something much more interactive and realtime like Vue/React.